# Map two lists into an inverted dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a series of genes that I would like to associate with a list of properties  and a color:

```
gene_A_color = red
gene_B_color = blue

gene_A_property = ['a','b','c']
gene_B_property = ['d','e','f']
```

For the purpose of plotting I would like to create a dictionary where I can use the property value as the key to get either the color or the gene as follows:

```
#lookup dictionary
{'a': ['red', 'gene_A']
 'b': ['red', 'gene_A']
 'c': ['red', 'gene_A']
 'd': ['blue' 'gene_B']
 'e': ['blue' 'gene_B']
 'f': ['blue' 'gene_B']}
lookup[a][0] = red
lookup[a][1] = gene_A
```

I started off as so but can only invert the list if I lose the gene name:

```
lookup_dict = defaultdict(list)
    lookup_dict['red'] =  ['a','b','c']
    lookup_dict['blue'] =  ['d','e','f']
inverted    = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in lookup_dict.items():
    inverted[v].append( k )

#inverted
{'a': 'red'
 'b': 'red'
 'c': 'red'
 'd': 'blue'
 'e': 'blue'
 'f': 'blue' }
```

suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You already have everything you need, an association of genes with properties. Everything else just kind of works itself out.

Why not use a class to represent the genes?

```
class Gene(object):
    def __init__(self, color, properties):
        self.color = color
        self.properties = properties

geneA = Gene('red', ['a', 'b', 'c'])
geneB = Gene('blue', ['d', 'e', 'f'])
genes = [geneA, geneB]

inverted = {}
for gene in genes:
    for prop in gene.properties:
        inverted[prop] = gene.color
```

Comment: good call. i could make the class also have gene.name and do inverted[prop] = [gene.color, gene.name]  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In case you just want a couple of simple statements to do this:

```
>>> gene_A_property = ['a','b','c']
>>> gene_B_property = ['d','e','f']
>>> ld={k:['red','gene_A'] for k in gene_A_property}
>>> ld.update({k:['blue','gene_B'] for k in gene_B_property})
>>> ld
{ 'a': ['red', 'gene_A'], 
  'c': ['red', 'gene_A'], 
  'b': ['red', 'gene_A'], 
  'e': ['blue', 'gene_B'], 
  'd': ['blue', 'gene_B'], 
  'f': ['blue', 'gene_B']
}
```